# given 2 point and 2 direction how do I know if they intersect?

Tags: c#, math, vector

I am doing some collision test in c#, and I have the following problem.

I have object1 and object2, they move in a direction.

I want to activate an effect only if object1 and object2 are colliding in a certain angle

the data I have

```
Vector2 object1Position
Vector2 object1Direction
float object1ColliderRadius

Vector2 object2Position
Vector2 object2Direction
float object2ColliderRadius
```

I already made a test to know if object1 is colliding with object2.

What I miss, is the angle of collision in order to activate or not something else in my code. follow this image .
[image]

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] if your progress so far.

Comment: What are the *sizes* of the objects? Even if their trajectories are crossing, the object s don't necessary collide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle is easily calculated from, e.g., the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product). The more interesting question is, if the two collide at all. This depends on the speed, of course. It is easily dealt with by adding an additional dimension. Here you'd put `z = t`. Using 3D affine geometry, you check if the 3D lines intersect. If yes, the objects with 2D trajectories collide. This is for point objects of course, so in detail you have to check for the closest distance of the lines.

Comment: assuming constant speed for now